# How to compare between 2 columns of same table in mongodb in PHP mongodb driver?

Tags: php, mongodb

Please provide me the precise answer to my question by checking the following example :

For example, Table: employees have fields (age1,age2)

I want to do SELECT query

```
Select count(*) From Employees Where age1 < age2
```

How can I do that in `mongodb` php driver functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:-

```
$db->empoyees->find( array('$where' => 'this.age1 < this.age2'  ) );
```

or

```
$db->empoyees->find(array('age1' => array('$lt' => 'age2')));
```

Comment: $db->empoyees->find(array('age1' => array('$lt' => 'age2'))); this is not working

Comment: How can I actually write that query using PHP mongodb driver :
$db->empoyees->find( array('$where' => 'this.age1 < this.age2'  ) );